2002 Ford Taurus
My Ford Taurus has been showing check engine light sometime solid sometimes flashing. Has rough idling uses way too much gas and slow acceleration. Recently the air conditioner has started blowing warm air so I filled it with freon and still the same output. But now that when the air condition comes on totally almost makes the car stall which in fact the other day rough idle by actually stalling.. please help

Autozone or other auto store nearby, providing free readings of error codes? Visit one. A flashing cel is points to catalytic converter damage if allowed to continue without attempting to decode stored error codes. A 22 yr old car has age related issues; worn out spark plugs (every 100k miles?), dirty throttle body, fuel filter (every 100k miles?), the catcon. A disintegrating or damaged catcon may rattle internally and randomly block off exhaust flow, strangling the exhaust system. Removing the downstream O2 sensor(s) may restore engine performance in a short drive. Fix the cel errors first.
